# How do you export to CSV from Excel with a custom separator using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I would like to export a number of excel files to .csv using a macro that specifies the column separator.

I've read that the way to get excel to export with a custom separator eg. "|" instead of "," is to  change the separator in the [Regional Settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-files-HP001130599.aspx) in your control panel.

I did this and it worked fine when I export a single file, however when I try to use a macro to export using the following snippet, the file still saves with the default comma separators.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Export\newfile.csv", FileFormat _
    :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Is there a method to save a file through VBA that will use the separator I have specified?

Comment: Consider looking at this [SO link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496686/how-to-save-semi-colon-delimited-csv-file-using-vba)

Comment: Got it. Setting the Local parameter to True did it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [excel macro save as CSV with ; separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265636/excel-macro-save-as-csv-with-separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code marked as solution for your question in another stackoverflow question.

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\Fredi.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
```

ref: [Save as CSV with semicolon separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265636/excel-macro-save-as-csv-with-separator)